# WPF Bing Maps Control - Change Scale Bar Units

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I'm trying out the Bing Maps control for WPF and this is driving me mad.

I can't figure out how to access the built-in scale bar so I can change the units to metric.

I can add a new scale bar, compass, etc. just fine but can't access the default one.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

An old question, but there is a much easier way to do this. Just set the Culture property on the map to a country that uses metric.

eg:

```
<m:Map 
  x:Name="MapObject" 
  CredentialsProvider="YOUR_KEY" 
  Center="-38.1231102,145.2116017" 
  ZoomLevel="11"  
  Mode="Aerial" 
  Culture="en-au"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy. Credit goes to whoever posted the FindVisualChild method on the Internet.

```
void SomeMethod()
{  
    var mapScale = FindVisualChild<Scale>(YourBingMapControl);
    mapScale.DistanceUnit = DistanceUnit.KilometersMeters;
}

static TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(DependencyObject obj) where TChildItem : DependencyObject
    {
    // Search immediate children first (breadth-first)
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child != null && child is TChildItem)
                return (TChildItem)child;
            else
            {
                var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(child);
                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```